# Take values from MySQL (in a class) into Listbox on a window

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to get values from a MySQL database, I created a separate class in order to create a better general overview for my teammates.

In the class I have this code:

```
public void missingOverview()
    {
        //missing items ophalen
        //connectie opzetten
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStr = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "localhost",
            Database = "GIPLouisThuyttenGregoireRobbe",
            UserID = "root",
            Password = "usbw",
            ConnectionTimeout = 60,
            Port = 3307,
            AllowZeroDateTime = true
        };
        MySqlConnection MySqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionStr.ConnectionString);

        //connectie aanmaken en query aanvragen
        try
        {
            //checken of de connectiestatus open of gesloten is, en zet deze open indien gesloten
            if (MySqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                MySqlCon.Open();
            //query aanvragen
            String query = "SELECT Username FROM login";
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, MySqlCon);

            MySqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                app.lsbMissingOverview.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Username"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlCon.Close();
    }
```

And in my window I have this code:

```
private void btnOverview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //overview toevoegen
        Overview overviewClass = new Overview();
        overviewClass.missingOverview();}
```

When the button is clicked no values show up, anybody know why?

Comment: Quick tip: Avoid share sensitive data in questions and answers

Comment: When you step through in a debugger, what happens?  Where specifically does it fail?  Does the method get called at all?  Does the query get executed?  Are there results?  What happens?

Comment: The query etc gets executed, the results just don't show up in the listbox, when I move this exact code to my window, it works, but in the class it doesn't.